# I how to bind keypress event to textboxes having same class

Tags: jquery

i have a table in which text-boxes are generated dynamically.each row has only one text box.all the text-boxes have same class(qt)and the table cell has a class (qty).i want to bind a keypress event so that only numbers can be entered so far i have coded a bit which is shown below please help.

```
 $("#qt").keypress(function(e) {
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) since the elements are created dynamically

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".qty", function (e) {
 //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

        return false;
    }

 });
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Comment: ur answer is correct but in place of qty it should be qt

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do like this:

```
 $(document).on('keypress','.qt',function(e) {
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

[**Fiddle DEMO using jquery 1.10.1**](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6j9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation -

```
$(document.body).on('keypress','.qt'function(e) {
 // do your stuff here
});
```

- https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Classes are specified using `.`, not `#` -- that's used for IDs. Since the textboxes are generated dynamically, you need to use event delegation:

```
$("#tableID").on('keypress', ".qt", function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```